# Why does this PHP objects code not work?

Tags: php

I'm currently reading the Objects chapter of "PHP, MySQL, Javascript" for Dummies and I can't get one of their examples to work, and I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.  This code is copied straight from the book:

CREATING CLASS

```
<?php
/* Class name:  Form
 * Description: A class that creates a simple HTML form
 *              containing only text input fields. The
 *              class has 3 methods.
 */
class Form {
  private $fields = array();  # contains field names and
   labels
  private $actionValue;     # name of script to process form
  private $submit = “Submit Form”; # value on submit button
  private $Nfields = 0; # number of fields added to the form
/* Constructor: User passes in the name of the script where
 * form data is to be sent ($actionValue) and the value to
 * display on the submit button.
 */
  function __construct($actionValue,$submit)
  {
     $this->actionValue = $actionValue;
     $this->submit = $submit;
  }
/* Display form function. Displays the form.
 */
  function displayForm()
  {
     echo “\n<form action=’{$this->actionValue}’
                   method=’POST’>\n”;
     for($j=1;$j<=sizeof($this->fields);$j++)
     {
       echo “<p style=’clear: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;
                padding-top: 5px’>\n”;
       echo “<label style=’float: left; width: 20%’>
                {$this->fields[$j-1][‘label’]}: </label>\n”;
       echo “<input style=’width: 200px’ type=’text’
                name=’{$this->fields[$j-1][‘name’]}’></p>\n”;
     }
     echo “<input type=’submit’ value=’{$this->submit}’
              style=’margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10px’>\n”;
     echo “</form>”;
}
/* Function that adds a field to the form. The user needs to
 * send the name of the field and a label to be displayed.
 */
   function addField($name,$label)
  {
    $this->fields[$this->Nfields][‘name’] = $name;
    $this->fields[$this->Nfields][‘label’] = $label;
    $this->Nfields = $this->Nfields + 1;
} }
?>
```

CREATE OBJECT AND HTML

```
<?php
/* Script name: buildForm
 * Description: Uses the form to create a simple HTML form
 */
require_once(“Form.class”);
echo “<html><head><title>Phone form</title></head><body>”;
$phone_form = new Form(“process.php”,”Submit Phone”);
$phone_form->addField(“first_name”,”First Name”);
$phone_form->addField(“last_name”,”Last Name”);
$phone_form->addField(“phone”,”Phone”);
echo “<h3>Please fill out the following form:</h3>”;
$phone_form->displayForm();
echo “</body></html>”;
?>
```

Comment: What happens? "Not working" isn't enough info to be able to offer suggestions from. Can you be more specific of the issues you face and what you've already tried? Do you get errors? White page or any output?

Comment: You have a whole bunch of curly quotes.

Comment: Don't code with a Word processor; use a code editor.

Comment: My favorite IDE editor (non-free, 30-day trial): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/, and my favorite non-IDE code editor (free): http://www.pspad.com/

Comment: CTRL-H is your friend today, as is John ;)

Comment: I'm using Sublime editor.  The book has tons of errors in it I'm finding, which is terrible if you're trying to learn.  I'm looking at the code in the book, and it contains these errors.  I've found other errors in their code examples as well.

Comment: Sublime is pretty cool, for utility. I've not been very satisfied using it as a primary editor, though some people swear by it. At any rate, the most important advice you got here is to turn on error reporting.

Comment: Are we talking about a physical book, or an E-book?

Comment: physical book:  you can see the code yourself at:http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111821370X.html   (book IV, Chapter 4)

Answer (score 5):

There are invalid quotes all over this file:

Change `“` and `”` to `"`

and `’` to `'`

PHP should have been throwing lots of errors here.

- You need to turn on [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) when developing new code.

Comment: MS Word has its advantages; just not for coding.

Comment: Yep. I also noticed these quotes in lots of blog posts about coding. Copy and paste will get you every time.

Comment: Some websites contain code that once you paste it into a file, they magically transform themselves into curlys; *simply amazing*.

Comment: A quick hit on CTRL-H will remedy this in a jiffy ;)